Wireguard with Opnsense - can't communicate with other machines
on a OpnSense I have already openvpn server set up and working with no issue. For some machine like OpenMediaVault I can only use wireguard so I'm considering leaving Openvpn toward WG or have both working
I have set up the server and few peers with no problem but I can't communicate with other machines within the tunnel.
In the firewall rules for the WG instance I left everything allowed in IN and OUT direction.
If I try to ssh connect to one remote machie, I can't find flow in the remote firewall.
Below my instance and peer config recap:
Instance name: WG0
pub and private key: autogenerated
port: 51820 (standard for the sake of testing)
Tunnel: 192.168.2.1/24
Peers: list of available peers configured

Peer:
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xxxxxx
Address = 192.168.2.2/24


[Peer]
PublicKey = ------(server pub key copied)
AllowedIPs = 192.168.2.0/24 ( I only want to connect machines connected to same WG instance. It works with Openvpn but may be not with WG?!)
Endpoint = wg.examples.com:51820


With OpnSense diagnostic I can see I have 5 peers connected but there is no way I can interact between these machines
Does anyone have a lead toward something to check? I tried to copy different tutorial but never being succesfull so far.
Helps is really welcome
cheers
